# How to apply different styles for custom visualforce component?

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component

I want to have the same custom visualforce component in two places, but apply different styles for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, you would need to put the styles would need to be at the Visualforce Page level, not the Visualforce Component level.

Best practice would be to include default styling at the Component level (e.g. if you just included the component, what would it look like?), then override Styles at the Page level. Remember, CSS is **Cascading Style Sheets** so if you have 3 `.css` files each containing a `colour` for the `p` tag but only one containing a `font-family`, the `colour` in the last sheet will get applied, but `font-family` will always get applied because it isn't overwritten.

For example:

**Style1.css**

```
p {
  font-family: Arial;
  color: red;
}
```

**Style2.css**

```
p {
  color: green;
}
```

**Style3.css**

```
p {
  color: blue;
}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css" /> // <p> colour doesn't get applied, font family does
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css" /> // <p> colour doesn't get applied
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style3.css" /> // <p> colour gets applied
```

In this example, the font style Arial gets applied because nothing overrides it, but the colour red is overwritten by the colour green which is overwritten by the colour blue.

I only say this because you'll need to think about where you apply your styles on your Visualforce page to get the effect you're after.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like Lightning does it: with a scope wrapper. That might look like this:

```
<style>
.SCOPE1 p {
    color: red;
}
.SCOPE2 p {
    color: green;
}
</style>

<apex:component>
    <apex:attribute name="scope" type="String" description="Which scope to use" />
    <div class="{!scope}">
        <p>My Color Depends On My Scope</p>
    </div>
</apex:component>
```

Using this would allow radically different styles to be applied depending on the attribute value supplied. Or, taking this one step further, you could even move the scope outside of the component:

```
<div class="SCOPE1">
    <c:myComponent />
</div>
<div class="SCOPE2">
    <c:myComponent />
</div>
```

This transfers a bit of complexity from inside the component to outside. Depending on the design you're going for, either might be acceptable.

Internally, this is how Salesforce Classic handles various page styles. For example, the only "style" difference between an account page and an opportunity page is that one has the style class "accountTab" while the other has the style "opportunityTab", which drives most of the coloring on the page specific to either tab. A good CSS design should minimize the amount of changes needed to get to either effect.